# Duplicate class com.facebook.jni - Can't build the app

Tags: android, react-native

After I changed the `compileSdkVersion` from 29 to 31, because I had to, it wouldn't build my app, and now I got this error.

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.CppException found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.CppSystemErrorException found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread$1 found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread$Destructor found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread$DestructorList found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread$DestructorStack found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.DestructorThread$Terminus found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.HybridClassBase found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.HybridData found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.HybridData$Destructor found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.IteratorHelper found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.MapIteratorHelper found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.ThreadScopeSupport found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.UnknownCppException found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.jni.annotations.DoNotStrip found in modules jetified-fbjni-0.3.0-runtime (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni:0.3.0) and jetified-fbjni-java-only-0.2 (com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2)```

I found this error -> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34328 similar to mine, but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my react-native info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.3.1
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 173.81 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.0.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 8.6.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.03.21.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.4, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.1 AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675
    Xcode: 13.3.1/13E500a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.15 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
    react-native: 0.64.2 => 0.64.2
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

I have tried results from the link I posted, but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is my android/build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }


    }
}
```

Here are dependencies from android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion

implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'

api 'com.facebook.fbjni:fbjni-java-only:0.2.2'
implementation 'org.pytorch:pytorch_android:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'

// For displaying GIFs
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
  exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
}

if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is RN related problem from November 4th. With the new update, they broke android builds for older RN versions. More info and fix -> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210